# Replacing the Ajaxfileupload control in a Windows Forms application

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

We have a windows forms legacy asp.net site that uses the AjaxFileUpload control to manage file uploads. One of our issues is that we have different file type uploads but these types are distinguished not by the extension, but by an element right before the extnsion, EG: .gh.zip vs. .gy.zip. It seems that if I add one of these, but not the other, to the AllowedFileTypes, it doesn't allow either.  Is it possible to piggyback some additional JS validation code to prevent an invalid file name, or would I need to replace the entire module with something else, and if so, what would be the recommendation for something that's going to be the least time-consuming that will offer a reasonable amount of configuratability?

Answer (score 0):

That control is open source - you can download the source and change it if you wish.

However, why would not just specifying zip as allowed file type work?

If I set a allowed extension of zip?

Then all of these work:

```
 .gh.zip     ok
 .gy.zip     ok
 .pdf        no
```

[image]

However, my markup is this:

```
      <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
            OnClientUploadCompleteAll="MyCompleteAll"  ChunkSize="16384"
            AllowedFileTypes="zip"                
            />
```

So, above only allows zip files.

if I try to say add a pdf file to above que, then I get this:

[image]

So just add allowed extension type = zip
(Edit: do NOT include the "." in this extension)

I not sure why that would not work?

But as noted, you can grab the source - it is open source code now.

However, I suspect perhaps some other issue is going on here?

Or maybe you need "more" complex file extensions parsing?

I mean, you could for the "rare" cases or say some "out liner" cases allow that file up-load, and THEN the post-processing code could reject the file type anyway, right?

However, looking at above, just specify file type = zip, and you should be ok.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  Basically the problem is that the REST of the file before the .zip is what I'm looking to screen, not the extension.  I DO have zip specified for the attribute, however, the site has different upload pages and those pages have different files you are supposed to upload.  On one page there's a XXXXgz.zip file and on another a XXXXgy.zip file (XXXX here is just the rest of the filename I don't care about right now).

Comment: The problem is that currently there is no way to stop the user from uploading the XXXXgy.zip file on the page that's supposed to be for XXXXgz.zip files and visa versa.  Now, On the back end I can just not save the file and alert the userNow, On the back end I can just not save the file and alert the user that it wasn't saved, but I'd prefer to stop the user from uploading it to begin with.